# Using Java 8 to convert a list of String into a list of Object

Tags: java, stream

There is a stream read from file, the content of each line is like:

```
 {"uid":"5981865218","timestamp":1525309552069,"isHot":true}
```

The class of User:

```
public class User {
    private String uid;
    private long timestamp;
    private boolean isHot;

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public boolean getIsHot() {
        return isHot;
    }

    public void setIsHot(boolean isHot) {
        this.isHot = isHot;
    }
}
```

The code that I want to get a list of Object 'List' from file stream:

```
BufferedReader targetBr = null;
targetBr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(targetUsersFile));
List<User> tmpUsers = targetBr.lines().?I don't know how process in there?.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You could use a deserializer (like Gson/Jackson) to deserialize the string to User objects

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialize the String to `User` objects. I have used Jackson [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) here (you could very well use others like Gson).

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
...
targetBr.lines()
        .map(line -> {
            try {
                return objectMapper.readValue(line, User.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `map` part of the stream takes a `Function` and hence you cannot throw a checked exception from there. Hence, I have wrapped the `IOException` that Jackson `readValue` throws (could throw) into a RuntimeException. You might have to change that part according to your need.

This is just a start. Think about what to do when there is an invalid entry that cannot be deserialized into a `User`. Some specific corner cases:

1. What if there is an unrecognized field (a property that is not present in the User class) in the input string. ObjectMapper in this case throws an `UnrecognizedPropertyException` exception. You can find ways to ignore it.
2. What if one or more of fields in the User class is missing in the String... Are some/all of them mandatory...?